# Knockout MVC - ServerAction call not executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, knockout.js

I am trying to build a website that is hosted on Azure as a free website, it is using MVC4, with KnockoutMVC. The website is updating a table every 4 seconds from the controller. The code executes without problem locally, however when I deploy it to the Azure website, it does not process updates.

I now have started a completely new MVC 4 project, with some simple functions using knockout, showing the current time, and updating this every .5 of a second from the controller, it is using the same structure as the javascript I have written for the proper website. It is giving the same problem, and it appears as if the ko.ServerAction call is halting the javascript function.

View

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model MVCHelloWorld.Models.HelloWorldModel
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
 }
<script type="text/javascript">
 function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    @ko.ServerAction("Index", "HelloWorld");

    t = setTimeout(function() { startTime(); }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}  
</script>

<body onload="startTime()">
   <h2>Hello World - 2</h2>
   <div id="time"></div>

   <label>Knockout time</label>
   @ko.Html.Span(m => m.Time)
</body>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Controller

```
namespace MVCHelloWorld.Controllers
{
  public class HelloWorldController : BaseController
  {

    public HelloWorldModel model = new HelloWorldModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GetTimeDoCalculation();

        return View();
    }

    public void GetTimeDoCalculation()
    {
        model.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss");
    }
 }
}
```

Model

```
namespace MVCHelloWorld.Models
{
public class HelloWorldModel
  {
     public string Time { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the site in a javascript console to see if there is an error being thrown, and to ensure that all entities are loaded as expected?

Comment: Yes, the Javascript is executing every 0.5 seconds as it should be and the javascript clock is loading then does not update again but the knockout doesn't load at all when it is published to the Azure website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the body of your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @* Replace 4000 with the timeout, in milliseconds *@
    window.setInterval(startTime, 4000)
</script>
```

Your entire view will look like this:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model MvcApplication2.Models.HelloWorldModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
 }
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

        @ko.ServerAction("Index", "HelloWorld");

        t = setTimeout(function() { startTime(); }, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }  
</script>

<body onload="startTime()">
   <h2>Hello World - 2</h2>
   <div id="time">

       <script type="text/javascript">
           @* Replace 4000 with the timeout, in milliseconds *@
           window.setInterval(startTime, 4000)
       </script>

       <label>Knockout time</label>
   @ko.Html.Span(m => m.Time)

   </div>
</body>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```